# Upload file from client side with jquery ajax call never getting the file selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have read some post here related but any one could help me out so far, I'm now trying upload a file selected in a input file in client side, then calling a server method using jquery ajax call, please how I'm doing it:

Sever Side Method:

```
       [WebMethod]public static void UploadDetailImageFromClient(string filename, string caption, string itemid, string inspid) {
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadBtn"]; if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) //See the id here include ContentPlaceHolder as I'm using a MasterPage, here is where I'm never getting the file, it comes NULL
        {
            string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine("images/", fname))) {
                file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("images/", fname)));
            }                
        }

    }
```

Client Side:

```
<td><asp:FileUpload ID="uploadBtn" runat="server" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"/></td>
```

This is the function I invoke to call the server method:

```
    function uploadnewpicture() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FormInspectionsMidPoint.aspx/UploadDetailImageFromClient",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ filename: filename, caption: caption, itemid: itemid, inspid: inspid }),
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadBtn").val("");
            jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtImageDetailCaption").val("");
            alert("Picture uploaded successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that I'm calling this javascript function from a input button on click event which is inside a jQuery dialog box. This is why I'm using an ajax call to keep the dialog box on as well as read the value in the input file from the client side as well. I am also using enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form.

I hope someone has had same scenario and can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Many years since I have used web forms and associated controls so please forgive me. Is the JS firing? Any errors in browser (firebug)? Are you debugging locally and stepping through the process server-side?

Comment: No errors calling the method, the method is firing well, as I said my only issue right now is this line:  HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadBtn"];  The file is null always.

Comment: As Request.Files returns a collection;  verify the count is 1, and then try to just use the first index (  Request.Files[0]  ) and see what is coming in.
What does firebug (or other browser inspector) show as being sent?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that:  HttpFileCollection filesCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
            var fileName = filesCollection[0]; however collection comes empty (0).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the Same Situation in my project. You can create a form data object in client side and add the file object to that form data object and pass to the controller. And receive the selected file from request in server side.

Client Side:-
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);

Server Side:-
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"]

Comment: Remember I'm using a "static" method in the server side (UploadDetailImageFromClient), means I can not use Request.Files unless I specify HttpContext.Current firstly, so HttpPostedFileBase and HttpPostedFile are not compatible implicitly, if I use HttpPostedFile instead I get the same issue (get null) even though I insert the file in the formdata (var data = new FormData(); data.append("file", file);)

Comment: I have seen that this is the most useful way to catch the object in the client side, using formdata, but in my case for some reason in the server side the collection File is always empty (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count), even though the function runs successfully... I'll create a new question only with this peace. Hopefully someone may help me out.